# How to loop through all the pages in site pages

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

I want read all the pages web part which is resides inside the site pages across site collection, sub site level. The code is below

```
$site = Get-SPSite 
# This is enough to select all webs in site collection, you don't need to select AllWebs
$webs = Get-SPWeb -Site $site -Limit ALL

# Iterate all webs
foreach ($web in $webs) {
    # Get SitePages library. If you have multiple libraries or use publishing,
    # you need to execute it for all libraries.
    $sitePages = $web.Lists.EnsureSitePagesLibrary()
    # This will only get files from root folder. You can use $folder.SubFolders to get all files
    $sitePages.RootFolder.Files | Select ServerRelativeUrl
}
$wpMngr = $SPweb.GetLimitedWebPartManager("",[System.Web.UI.WebControls.Webparts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared); #you could change the page
$listItemData=@()
foreach($wp in $wpMngr.WebParts)
{ 
Write-Host "Title" $wp.Title
Write-Host "TypeName" $wp
Write-Host "content" $wp.Content.InnerText 
Write-Host "content Link" $wp.ContentLink                       
Write-Host "PartOrder" $wp.PartOrder
Write-Host  "Zone"    $wp.ZoneID
Write-Host "Id" $wp.Id
Write-Host "Zone Index" $wp.ZoneIndex
Write-Host "Image Link" $wp.ImageLink
Write-Host "Media Link" $wp.MediaLink
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to check the web parts used in the pages in your site pages library. As you are not quite familiar with the `GetLimitedWebPartManager` method, it may better to first use a script here:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/08/find-all-web-parts-in-use-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html

And here is a blog about how to use this method. https://thechriskent.com/tag/getlimitedwebpartmanager/

Comment: you saved me.. thank you for the links

Comment: Along with this script i want to create log file which capture the errors.